# No icon with QStyleOptionButton

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qpushbutton

I have got a weird problem.

I need to have some buttons in my QTableView. I used to use  QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget() method, but it is not very responsible when working with larger models. Therefore I decided to switch to QStyledItemDelegate. My buttons have icons (and icons only, no text). When working with setIndexWidget, I used the following code:

```
ClientDetailsButton::ClientDetailsButton(const Client* _client,
                                         QWidget* _parent) :
    QPushButton("", _parent),
    __current(_client) {

  setIcon(QIcon(":/uiIcons/button-details.png"));
}
```

And it worked perfectly. But when I switch to delegate, I use it like that:

```
QStyleOptionButton button;
button.rect = _option.rect;
button.text.clear();
button.icon = QIcon(":/uiIcons/button-details.png");
button.state = _option.state | QStyle::State_Enabled;

if (_index == __button)
  button.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken;

QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, _painter);
```

The button itself is fine, but its empty. There is no icon visible. Suprisingly, when I use, for example:

```
button.icon = QIcon::fromTheme("dialog-information", QIcon(":/uiIcons/button-details.png"));
```

the theme icon is visible. But if Qt cannot find the theme icon, the replacement is still blank. I tried everything I could think of and have no idea why it doesn't work. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Why you can't draw an icon directly?

Comment: Its soo complicated and I can never be sure if it looks OK on every machine...

Comment: What you mean by "complicated"? Making call `painter->drawPixmap` instead of all your code?

Comment: No, I want button there. By complicated I mean making the pixmap looks like a standard image on button.

Comment: Draw button - then draw image on it. Still complex? :)

Comment: Yes, its not that simple. Whats more, its only workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Using of delegates is not a workaround.

Comment: Rendering an icon separately is not a solution.

Comment: It's your opinion. If you want to talk instead of using Qt-ways - you should wait for other answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting `button.iconSize=QSize(16,16);` as the default iconsize is `(-1,-1)` so the icon is invisible.